# Remove leading/trailing spaces without isspace()

Tags: c, pointers, space, isspace

I was looking for a standard way to remove leading spaces, and I found a pretty simple way using pointers and `isspace()`, however our professor won't allow us to use the `<ctype.h>` library. Would the following work?

```
char LeadingSpace(char *line) {
    while (line[0] == ' ') {
        line++;
    }
    return line;
}
```

I'm new to C so not entirely sure how pointers work, but if I move the pointer everytime I find a leading space, then I would only have to check `line[0]`, right?

Comment: Yes this code would do what you want, however, if `line` was allocated using `malloc()` you cannot use the returned pointer for `free()`. Also, it seems that you missed a `*` in the function definition. And finally, you should be aware that `isspace()` not only ignores `' '` but `'\t'`, `'\n'` and `'\r'` too.

Comment: @iharob Alright, thanks so much! Learned a lot just from that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Checking `line[0] == ' '` is fine:

But this line

```
char LeadingSpace(char *line) {
```

should be

```
char* LeadingSpace(char *line) {
```

As you are returning a character pointer

Comment: I have a doubt. In the question is he returning a character?

Comment: Please re-read - the type of line is `char *` - the bit I corrected

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
char* LeadingSpace(char *line) {
    while (line[0] == ' ' || line[0] == '\t' || line[0] == '\n' || line[0] == '\r') {
        line++;
    }
    return line;
}
```

or this using string.h header

```
char* LeadingSpace(char *line) {
    while (strchr(" \t\r\n", line[0])) {
        line++;
    }
    return line;
}
```

Comment: Note that using a switch would be clearer. The `strchr()` trick is very nice.